# How to change Eclipse folder structure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets

I have converted Dynamic Web Project to Maven project and no more able to run it in Eclipse due to change in project structure. How can I set `src` as my project src folder and `WebContent` folder as my HTML, CSS, JS folder and `WEB-INF` as my `web.xml`?

Here is my project explorer:

WebContent:

[image: WebContent]

Project Folders Structure:

[[image: Project Folders Structure]
Tomcat 404 for Servlet:

[image: Tomcat 404 for Servlet]

Tomcat 404 for HTML Files:

[image: Tomcat 404 for HTML Files]

Right now I am not able to run any java servlet or html file from aforementioned folder structure

Comment: Do not use images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/296328

Comment: Thanks to all who are assisting me to format or advise how to post question in this community. I am learning...

Comment: https://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/ might help

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam the problem is not how to convert project to maven project but to change directory structure in eclipse. Thanks for replying to my question

Comment: @JimmyY if I understood correctly, you want to change the directory structure to maven default structure?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Yes, You are right

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to follow [*Maven / Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout*](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

If you right-click on a Maven project (or a folder within) in the *Package Explorer* or *Project Explorer* view there is *Build Path* →:

- → *New Source Folder...*
- → *Use as Source Folder*
- → *Configure Build Path* → *Source* tab → <kbd>Add Folders...</kbd>